# How does Firebase Dashboard filter work when user properties value changed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Firebase Dashboard has filter function that can filter user by the user's user properties value.

When user properties value changed fron "A" to "B", and in the selected duration both log that has "A" and log that has "B" contain, how does the filter work about the user?

I guess it's one of the below..

- Filter works as the user's value is "B" (the user is counted when filter set "B", not when filter set "B")
- Filter works as the user's value is "A" AND "B" (the user is counted both filter set "A" and filter set "B")

Comment: You should reach out to firebase support for server/website questions.

Comment: Thanks, maybe so. But I don't have support contract..

Comment: You don't need a support contract to send them an email about a website function.